# I am trying to run a shell script from Jenkins server on my ubuntu Machine

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am trying to run a shell script from Jenkins server on my ubuntu Machine.
But, after triggering the script, is says:

Error: disable canonical input processing

What is the issue? And Please let me know, how to fix it.

TIA

This is the complete log :

Started by user Dharmendra Koppineni
Building remotely on 172.16.20.41 (41) in workspace

/home/ranzure/jenkins/workspace/Cloud_RAN--BBU--XTA_Automation_Test

[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...

[WS-CLEANUP] Done

No emails were triggered.

[Cloud_RAN--BBU--XTA_Automation_Test] $ /bin/sh -xe

/tmp/jenkins3477907176599520067.sh

- cd /home/ranzure/jenkins/workspace/Cloud_RAN--BBU--XTA_Automation_Test
- cd /home/ranzure/dharmendra/view/bbu/l2l3/src/acceptance/enbapp
- ./wr_acc

g_power is 5

**Error: disable canonical input processing**

SInit(): Could not initialize the Logging streams

SInit failed, SSI could not start

Archiving artifacts

‘*’ doesn’t match anything

ERROR: Step ‘Archive the artifacts’ failed: No artifacts found that match the

file pattern "*". Configuration error?

Email was triggered for: Failure - Any

Sending email for trigger: Failure - Any

An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.

Finished: FAILURE

1. List item

Comment: Share the complete error details of jenkins jobs

Comment: hi, addded the complete log.